# How do I filter through results when using Angular-Translate + ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I am using Angular-Translate since I have a website in 2 languages in conjunction with Angular-Material.

To populate my `<md-grid-tile>` I use `ng-repeat` a bit differently.

```
<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="items in tabsCtrl.countProducts track by $index" ...
```

First I count the amount of arrays in JSON file by getting the value of `vm.countProducts` variable which I get through this method

```
JsonData.all(vm.pathToJson[1]).then(function(response) {
      vm.namespaceProducts = Object.keys(response.data);
      vm.countProducts = JsonData.setObjectCount(Object.keys(response.data[vm.namespaceProducts]).length);
```

Here is JsonData service method

```
setObjectCount: function(n) {
        return new Array(n);
      }
```

This way, ng-repeat cycles the exact needed amount of times and Angular-Translate populates the values inside.

**The problem** is that I can no longer use `| filter : search` on

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ... >

<md-grid-tile ng-repeat="items in tabsCtrl.countProducts track by $index" | filter : search ...
```

It throws an error since I repeating not an array/object but just numbers

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/filter/notarray?p0=0

> Error: filter:notarray Not an array Expected array but received: 0

I am still very new to this whole AngularJS framework, but the error is quite obvious, **I need a custom filter.** I have no idea though where to start with custom filter, could anyone provide a sample code that would work so I can grasp the idea of where/how to implement it properly.

I host all my code on github https://github.com/Nikki1993/zmed if you need a bigger picture of how I do things (pardon in advance for all the bad code quality, if any, still learning)

Comment: There is some code missing there. What does `JsonData.setObjectCount` do? If the output is really an array - as it should always be for ngRepeat, try putting the expression in parenthesis (except for the filter), angular might just mess up the order of execution.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the setObjectCount function. The only thing it does is it returns new array. so if there is 3 object the array would consist of name = {0,1,2}

Comment: @Gant I've also added the link to github repo where I sync my work to, if it helps you to get a better picture of how I go through ng-repeat.